Modding Minecraft Forge 1.20.4: How do i make minecraft use my modified version of a class instead of the original one for existing stuff?
i´m trying to tell minecraft to use my modyfied candle block class for the existing candle-block.
This post Change final variable defined in another java file told, that it should be possible to override ecisting classes from minecraft by recreating the original package-path from the minecraft referenced library into the src/java folder of the mod and put the changed class with original name in there.
But now i get an error:
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules candlepositionsmod and minecraft export package net.minecraft.world.level.block to module forge at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveFail(Resolver.java:901) at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.failTwoSuppliers(Resolver.java:815) at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.checkExportSuppliers(Resolver.java:736)
How to fix?
